# How to learn JQuery within a week?

Tags: jquery

I am under a project which requires extensive JQuery and I am very new to it. I have a good knowledge about JavaScript but am almost a starter in JQuery. I want you guys to propose a tutorial so that I can get most of JQuery within a week. Coz my project delivery date is too near and they really need a person who knows JQuery in depth. Is there some tutorial that can teach me JQuery on the fly?? pls give me appropriate resource if possible.
Thanks

Comment: If you have good knowledge of JavaScript, learning jQuery should be quite easy. Here is a list of tutorials: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Comment: look at the jquery api and everything's there

Comment: jquery and ajax take far less than a week to learn. just by looking at some basic tutorials and the api you can learn much. jquery itself has not too many functions thus it is pretty easy and fast to get into.

Comment: I understand and will try getting along with it. Some links are really useful!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/

Whenever you need to access a number of elements, use jQuery.
Whenever you need to do some AJAX or JSON-webservice calls, use jQuery.

Read the API docs.

Practice. You won't learn if you don't try to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "learn" anything properly in a week. And tutorials are not as good as books.

I suggest looking through the jQuery documentation and examples; other than that, you're just up against it really. Perhaps consider alternative solutions to your problem that don't involve learning an entirely new tool a week before a deadline.

Answer (score 1):

Follow documentation in Jquery website.
going through answers of this question
https://stackoverflow.com/q/1152369/397540

can help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several good tutorials on jQuery on the jQuery site itself.

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

jQuery is so easy you'll get the hang of it in no time

Answer (score 0):

The way I thought myself jQuery was by searching google.
You can get answers to most of your questions by checking there.

Also: [http://www.google.se/search?q=learning+jquery](http://www.google.se/search?q=learning%20jquery)

Answer (score 0):

If you already know JavaScript and how the DOM works, jQuery is just a set of API calls that you don't need to remember.

I've been using jQuery for years and I still can't remember how to append a DOM element to a node, is it `.insert()`, `.append()`? Who cares, there's the docs.

What's important is that you have good intuition of the DOM and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery tutorials page has literally 100's of tutorials on this `http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials` the ajax framework was totally rewritten from v1.5 so you should be good to start with the ajax API `http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/`

if you are learning Ajax then there should be some server side framework you already know ;D learn how to compress and format data using that server side language into jSon format/ xml format. Learn the javascript paterns from the Apress books i found these two really awesome

http://books.google.com/books?id=M3Uqna8RIAkC&pg=PA486&dq=apress+javascript&hl=en&ei=ndeeTfyREo3prQeO1e3_Ag&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=apress%20javascript&f=false

http://books.google.com/books?id=za3vlnlWxb0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=apress+javascript&hl=en&ei=ndeeTfyREo3prQeO1e3_Ag&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=apress%20javascript&f=false

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn jQuery:

1. Download and Install [HelpMesh](http://www.helpmesh.com/installer/HelpMesh_Setup.zip).
2. Add the jQuery eBook in HelpMesh.
3. Browse a Page in jQuery eBook.
4. Click the Console button in bottom of page.
5. Run script: Shell.Run('jQuery');
6. Then test any jQuery method, example: var x=$('body');